# Reusing the Partial View with binded knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js, view, partial

In Landing Page, I applied bindings to the partial View. ("myModalSeeAllDrafts")

Landing Page:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/JumpStartYourJourney/_SeeAllDrafts.cshtml")

var journeyDrafts = {
                dataUrl: '@Url.Action("GetSeeAllDraftsData", "Home")',
                selectUrl: '@Url.Action("GetDraftJourney", "Home")',
                deleteUrl: '@Url.Action("DeleteDraftBooking", "Home")'
            };

 var journeyDraftsVM = new JourneyDraftsViewModel(journeyDrafts);
            ko.applyBindings(journeyDraftsVM, $("#myModalSeeAllDrafts")[0]);
```

I wanted to **reuse the partial** from another view

Traveller View:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/JumpStartYourJourney/_SeeAllDrafts.cshtml")

var url = {
            dataUrl: '@Url.Action("GetSeeAllDraftsData", "Home")',
            selectUrl: '@Url.Action("GetDraftJourney", "Home")',
            deleteUrl: '@Url.Action("DeleteDraftBooking", "Home")',
        };
        var journeyDraftsViewModel = new JourneyDraftsViewModel(url);
        ko.applyBindings(journeyDraftsViewModel, $("#myModalSeeAllDrafts")[0]);
```

I got an error, Uncaught Syntax Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
Isn't it that, once you got to another page, the binded from that view is already been expired?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change second binding to this: `$("#myModalSeeAllDrafts")[1]`

but this is not a good approach since you have 2 or more elements have the same id: you can send id as parameter for containing element in partialview.

```
@Html.Partial("_SeeAllDrafts", "id2")
@Html.Partial("_SeeAllDrafts", "id1")
```

and in partial:

```
@model string

<div id='@Model'>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
```

Then change your bindings to

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var journeyDraftsViewModel = { name: "refan" };
            ko.applyBindings(journeyDraftsViewModel, document.getElementById('id1'));
            ko.applyBindings(journeyDraftsViewModel, document.getElementById('id2'));
        });
    </script>
}
```

---------------------OR-----------------------

You can wrap your partials with the div that have different ids:

```
<div id="id1">
    @Html.Partial("_SeeAllDrafts")
</div>

<div id="id2">
    @Html.Partial("_SeeAllDrafts")
</div>

$(function () {
     var journeyDraftsViewModel = { name: "refan" };
     ko.applyBindings(journeyDraftsViewModel, document.getElementById('id1'));
     ko.applyBindings(journeyDraftsViewModel, document.getElementById('id2'));
});
```

then do the binding according to this ids.

-------------------if you don't have any other binding----------------------

You can do the binding one time after to entire page at document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var journeyDraftsViewModel = new JourneyDraftsViewModel(url);
    ko.applyBindings(journeyDraftsViewModel);
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip irfan, I followed every tip you've provide but still I got an Uncaught Syntax Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. Except for having another argument to an Html.Partial (providing id), I got an InvalidOperationException

Comment: i have updated my answer, made amistake on parameter passing to view.

Comment: I have a question. Currently I have a model in my partial view. Can you tell me how to put two models in one view? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I already modified my code. And yes, the ViewModel is working to the 2 views, thank you for that, but I still get caught by the uncaught syntax error about I cannot apply bindings multiple times. The partial view works well but other functionality of the view (especially the second applybindings) are not.

Comment: you cant apply bindings to the same portion of page more than one.  look at the page source and search for "applyBindings"